# New Environments in limecv

Tags: cv

In limecv only environments like cvEducation, cvExperience, cvSkills are defined. I want to create a new heading "Trainings" in the resume. How can I do this using limecv.

I am using this tex template from github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opieters/limecv/master/examples/mwe-latex.tex  and using Pdflatex to compile it.

I want to add an additional section "Training" in the main content part of the resume.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can mimic the [limecv source](https://github.com/opieters/limecv/blob/master/src/limecv.dtx#L1808):

```latex
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvTraining}{}{%
    \cv@Title{Training}{\faForward}
    \stepcounter{cv@itemPrev}
    \stepcounter{cv@itemNext}
    \cv@definecvItem
}{%
    \cv@EndSectionDraw
    \stepcounter{cv@lastItem}
    \draw (item \the\value{cv@itemPrev}.south west)
    node (cv@last item \the\value{cv@lastItem}) {};
}
\makeatother
```

Since the OP didn't provide a minimal working example, here's one based on the [example mwe](https://github.com/opieters/limecv/blob/master/examples/mwe-latex.tex) taken from the limecv GitHub repo, including the custom environment:

[image: output of mwe]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{limecv}

\usepackage[margin=\cvMargin,noheadfoot]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvTraining}{}{%
    \cv@Title{Training}{\faForward}
    \stepcounter{cv@itemPrev}
    \stepcounter{cv@itemNext}
    \cv@definecvItem
}{%
\cv@EndSectionDraw
\stepcounter{cv@lastItem}
\draw (item \the\value{cv@itemPrev}.south west)
node (cv@last item \the\value{cv@lastItem}) {};
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{cvMainContent}
        \begin{cvEducation}
            \cvItem{Evening class: How to take care of ducks\\
            University of Quack, Ducktown. September 2015 -- June 2016\\
            Raised a duckling to fully grown and released into the wild.
            }
            \cvItem{Master of Duck Theory\\
            University of Quack, Ducktown. September 2012 -- June 2015\\
            All about ducks.
            }
        \end{cvEducation}

        \begin{cvTraining}
            \cvItem{How to walk like a duck \\
            Living room, April 2019 \\
            Dance of the ducks.}
            \cvItem{Quack quack quack! \\
            Quack quack? 2017}
        \end{cvTraining}
    \end{cvMainContent}
\end{document}
```